# Getting group by attribute in nested query

Tags: postgresql, group-by, subquery

I am trying to find the most frequent value in a postgresql table. The problem is that I also want to "group by" in that table and only get the most frequent from the values that have the same name.
So I have the following query:

```
select name,
  (SELECT value FROM table where name=name GROUP BY value ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC limit 1)
as mfq from table group by name;
```

So, I am using `where name=name`, trying to get the outside group by attribute "name", but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas on how to do it?

Edit: for example in the following table:

```
name    value
 a          3
 a          3
 a          3
 b          2
 b          2
```

I want to get:

```
name    value
 a          3
 b          2
```

but the above statement gives:

```
name    value
 a          3
 b          3
```

instead, since where doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results? Your explanation is hard to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your query to work, you need table aliases.  Table aliases and qualified column names are *always* a good idea:

```
select t.name,
       (select t2.value
        from table t2
        where t2.name = t.name 
        group by t2.value 
        order by COUNT(*) desc
        limit 1
       ) as mfq
from table t
group by t.name;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a dedicated function in PostgreSQL for this case: the [`mode()` ordered-set aggregate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html):

```
select   name, mode() within group (order by value) mode_value
from     table
group by name;
```

which *returns the most frequent input value (arbitrarily choosing the first one if there are multiple equally-frequent results)* -- which is the same behavior as with your `order by count(*) desc limit 1`.

It is available from PostgreSQL 9.4+.

http://rextester.com/GHGJH15037